# Python async unit tests, how to use async database connection pool?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I'm using `Python 3.9.7`, `databases 0.4.3`, `asyncpg 0.24.0`.

Relevant files/snippets:

#### tests.py

```
from unittest import TextTestRunner, TestSuite, TestLoader

runner = TextTestRunner()
test_loader = TestLoader()
suite = TestSuite()
test_suite = add_tests_to_suite(suite)  # <- All my tests are added here

runner.run(test_suite)
```

#### db.py

```
from databases import Database
dal = Database()  # This is the "Databases" lib instance
```

#### some_test.py

```
from unittest import IsolatedAsyncioTestCase
from db import dal

class SomeTest(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def some_async_test(self):
        try:
            await dal.connect()
            # Test logic happens here
        finally:
            await dal.disconnect()
```

The code above *works*, however, connecting and disconnecting on every unit test is taking around 400ms, which is very slow when dealing with a large amount of unit tests. What is the proper/recommended way of dealing with async database connections in the context of unit tests?

Things I tried:

- Move `dal.connect()` to `tests.py`, but that file is not in the asyncio context, therefore I cannot `await` the `connect()` function.
- Create an asyncio loop in `tests.py` just so I can `await` the `connect()` function, but this approach throws:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'IsolatedAsyncioTestCase._asyncioLoopRunner' was never awaited`

- Run the function `dal.connect()` only once, rather than on every test, but it throws:

> asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress